# MediaWiki - Show file usage

Tags: php, reference, mediawiki

I've written an extension for `MediaWiki` that creates slideshow for images.

The problem is that while the image is used in the slideshow it doesn't show it is being used on the file page. How can I add page reference to `File Usage` section?

Comment: You'll need to create an entry in the link table for that. Could you show us the code of your plugin?

Comment: @Bergi: Here is main part of code: http://pastebin.com/HGu2HiuT

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the image to the list of images in the ParserOutput object. You can get a ParserOutput object by calling `$parser->getOutput()`, and add an image to it with `$parserOutput->addImage( $name )`.